# Why is there a blank space in the div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a form inside. The form is just a text input and a button. But when i set the width of the textinput to, for example, 100%, it fills only about a third of the div. Im not able to fill the div with the two parts of the form. Theres always a big white space on the right side of the div.
When the textinput is bigger then any special size, the button is pushed to the next line.

```css
#searcharea {
  margin-top: 7.5px;
  margin-bottom: 7.5px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width:300px;
  background-color: #0000FF;
}

#textinput {
  margin-top: 2.5px;
  margin-bottom: 2.5px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#button { 
  background-image: url("images/searchtool.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  border: none;
  width: 20%;
  height: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id='searcharea' >
  <form method='GET' style='display:inline-block'>
    <input type='text' name='userinput' id='textinput' placeholder='test'>
    <input type='submit' id='button' value=' '>
  </form>
</div>
```

I expected the textinput and button to fill the whole div. 
But when i set the width of the textinput up to 80%, the button is placed next to it, like intendet. But they fill just about the half of the div.
When the width is above 80%, the button is put to the next line.

Here are pictures of the two situations:
https://unsee.cc/c3a6cf03/

Comment: Change `<form style='display:inline-block'>` to  `<form style='display:block'>`. At the moment your `<form>` is only as wide as needed, so setting display:block enlargens it to the whole width

Comment: thank you so much! I overlooked this detail so many times.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Display:flex** on the form and give **flex-basis:100%** to the "#textinput".

```css
#searcharea {
  margin-top: 7.5px;
  margin-bottom: 7.5px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width:300px;
  background-color: #0000FF;
}

#textinput {
  margin-top: 2.5px;
  margin-bottom: 2.5px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  align-self: center;
 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#button { 
  background-image: url("images/searchtool.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  border: none;
  width:50px;
  height: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
   align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div id='searcharea' >
  <form method='GET' style='display:flex'>
    <input type='text' name='userinput' id='textinput' placeholder='test'>
    <input type='submit' id='button' value=' '>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `style='display:inline-block'` from the `form` element in your html

```css
#searcharea {
    margin-top: 7.5px;
    margin-bottom: 7.5px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width:300px;
    background-color: #0000FF;
}

#textinput {
    margin-top: 2.5px;
    margin-bottom: 2.5px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 35px;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#button {   
    background-image: url("images/searchtool.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    border: none;
    width: 20%;
    height: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id='searcharea' >
  <form method='GET'>
    <input type='text' name='userinput' id='textinput' placeholder='test'>
    <input type='submit' id='button' value=' '>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution.

You use flexbox on the form and for its children (textbox & search button) you use flex: 0 0 auto and flex: 1.

This means that the width of the button will be set by css (width: 50px;) and on the input you set flex:1 which means that it will take all the available space minus the width of the button. So even if you increase/decrease the width of the container (#searcharea) the searchform will still be displayed properly.

```css
#searcharea {
  
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  
  width:300px;
  background-color: #0000FF;
}
.searchform{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
#textinput {
  height: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  outline:none;
  padding:0px 8px;
  border-radius:20px 0 0px 20px;
  flex:1;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#button {
flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-image: url("images/searchtool.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  border: none;
  width:50px;
  height: 35px;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

```html
<div id='searcharea' >
  <form method='GET' class="searchform">
    <input type='text' name='userinput' id='textinput' placeholder='test'>
    <input type='submit' id='button' value=' '>
  </form>
</div>
```